# PostgreSQL table relation problems in Rails migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pg

Im getting this error when i run `heroku run rails db:migrate`....

```
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "matches" does not exist
: CREATE TABLE "picks" ("id" bigserial primary key, "week_score_id" bigint, "picked_team_id" bigint, "match_id" bigint, "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_60b2712d81"
FOREIGN KEY ("week_score_id")
  REFERENCES "week_scores" ("id")
, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_efd026f22b"
FOREIGN KEY ("match_id")
  REFERENCES "matches" ("id")
)
```

development is in sqlite and production in pg

my guess is my table relations are incorrect?

first I thought this problem was because of me generating models using the `match:references` so in the models i had `belongs_to :match` and in the migration files i had `t.references :match`. I switch all belongs_tos to :match_id and also changed migration file `match_id:integer`  and `ran rails db:reset`
but it still wont work :(

Comment: You try to create `picks` table before `matches` table is created.

Comment: lol that worked. Is it safe to use `match:references` ?

Comment: Do you mean `t.references :match` syntax?